# Secure development setup for Android

Tags: java, android, security

This may be an ignorant question, but I am trying to set up an Android development environment on both Windows and Mac OS X and want to make sure I don't screw anything up.  With all the Java vulnerabilities security of my development machine is a paramount concern.  Is there a "best practice" for ensuring a secure development environment, are people developing in VMs or is the security a non-issue if I simply don't have the browser extensions installed?

To summarize, does installing the JDK open up the machine to unnecessary risk of drive by attacks or do those vulnerabilities strictly come from the browser plugin?

Comment: if you're worried about security, unplug your LAN cable or disable your wi-fi.  That's the only way to really make sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your biggest concern is the the JavaApplet plugin, which will doubtless get installed alongside the JDK, and which you very likely don't ever want.

The following removes it with extreme prejudice:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
```

There is a case for setting up a cron job to do this periodically, just to be sure it doesn't creep back in.

As it happens, MacOSX is fairly conscientious at disabling it when there are security vulnerabilities reported (which is to say, fairly often), and then require the user explicitly re-enable it.

As for your dev tools: both Eclipse and Intellij are Java-based.  Obtain them only from reputable sources and check the md5 hashes if available.

Answer (score 2):

For the most part you should be fine.  You are developing against SDKs and will be testing on your own devices or emulators.  You will also likely be using a source control and that's where you want to take in best practices.

Any files containing security keys, API keys, passwords or any sensitive information should be ignored and not put into source control.  I like to keep my signing keys in a separate folder completely outside source control.  This is probably where the biggest security vulnerabilities may lie; if any of these files make it to version control, revoke and regenerate them immediately.